# Why is the Elixir.Phoenix.Codeloader.Server on top in this :observer screen?

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am on a quest to find out where my Phoenix app spends it CPU cycles. People have recommended I take a look at the :observer tool, but I have trouble interpreting its output. See the screen below:

[image: observer process screen]

Quick description of the app: it accepts REST calls with JWT, and depending on the user in the JWT forwards the call to a backend server.

I assume that the 'Reds' column more or less corresponds to the cpu usage. So:

- what is the CodeReloader server and why is it on top?
- what is the file_server process and why is it so high, I'm not doing any File I/O
- Why is the Elixir.Logger so high? I don't get any logging output
  during my testrun, and I'm using lazy logging.
- what is the code server process doing during my test run?
- why are all those cowboy_protocol.init processes so high, I would expect initialisation being quick, but other functions more expensive.
- the jose_server is the only thing I can understand, it decrypts the JWTs

For reference, here is the etop output for a similar testrun, how do I get it to show time values instead of '-'? And do I want that?

```
Pid            Name or Initial Func    Time    Reds  Memory    MsgQ Current Function
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<0.247.0>      'Elixir.Phoenix.Code     '-'24468015 2178040      13 gen:do_call/4
<0.46.0>       file_server_2            '-'14085904  197128       0 gen_server:loop/7
<0.642.0>      hackney_pool:init/1      '-'  795169   14368       0 gen_server:loop/7
<0.416.0>      jose_server              '-'  483301   18728       0 gen_server:loop/7
<0.323.0>      'Elixir.Logger'          '-'  254592   30680       0 gen_event:fetch_msg/
<0.96.0>       'Elixir.Mix.ProjectS     '-'  184593  689560       0 gen_server:loop/7
<0.374.0>      hackney_manager          '-'  155632  125504       0 gen_server:loop/7
<0.3121.0>     cowboy_protocol:init     '-'  132982   47368       0 gen:do_call/4
<0.3117.0>     cowboy_protocol:init     '-'  132979   47368       0 gen:do_call/4
<0.3119.0>     cowboy_protocol:init     '-'  132978   47368       0 gen:do_call/4
<0.3120.0>     cowboy_protocol:init     '-'  132978   47368       0 gen:do_call/4
```

Comment: Looks like it's on top because it's sorting descending on reductions (Reds). As far as what it is, check this: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.CodeReloader.html

Comment: Translation for posterity: I was running this in MIX_ENV=dev and the code reloader checks if my code needs a recompilation on every HTTP request. This probably also explains the file_server being on top.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To summarize my findings:

Turns out I was running in :dev mode, and in dev mode configuration is different. For example you can edit your source code, and on the next HTTP request the Code Reloader will detect the change and quickly recompile the code. So when I hammered the server with requests, to Code Reloader was continuously checking all my source files, which also explains why the file_server just below it was so busy. I switched to production mode (MIX_ENV=prod) and performance tripled.

About the Logger: I had set the loglevel as high as :error and no output was shown. But, I like to do a lot of logging, and my log statements pretty much describe all decisions made in a program, so for each HTTP request there were like tens of logging statements present in the code. That tends to add up, especially if you do hundreds of requests per second.

Thankfully you can tell the Elixir compiler to completely remove those statements from production: use the compile_time_purge_level flag in the logger configuration (in `config/prod.exs`):

```
# Do not print debug messages in production
config :logger, level: :warn, compile_time_purge_level: :info
```

Finally I used the `fprof` profiler, which determined that the JWT processing was the culprit, and I decided to stop there.

Here’s how to do that:

```
iex(5)> :fprof.trace([:start, {:procs, :all}])
:ok
iex(6)> :fprof.trace(:stop)
:ok
iex(7)> :fprof.profile
...................................,
(and a whole lot more lines)
End of trace!
:ok
iex(8)> :fprof.analyse([callers: true, sort: :own, totals: true, details: true])
(followed by > 1000 lines of output)
Done!
:ok
```

Note that fprof generates huge output files (fprof.trace in the current directory), even when tracing for only a minute.

Here is the first part of the fprof.analyse() call:

```
iex(5)> :fprof.analyse([callers: true,sort: :own,totals: true,details: true])
Processing data...
Creating output...
%% Analysis results:
{  analysis_options,
 [{callers, true},
  {sort, own},
  {totals, true},
  {details, true}]}.
%                                               CNT       ACC       OWN
[{ totals,                                     4774694,17162.356,14837.297}].  %%%
{[{{base64url,'-decode/1-lbc$^0/2-0-',2},      206492,    0.000,  829.718},
  {{base64url,decode,1},                       1083, 1191.294,    5.680}],
 { {base64url,'-decode/1-lbc$^0/2-0-',2},      207575, 1191.294,  835.398},     %  <----------
 [{{base64url,'-decode/1-lbc$^0/2-0-',2},      206492,    0.000,  829.718},
  {{base64url,urldecode_digit,1},              206492,  350.686,  348.324},
  {garbage_collect,                             620,    5.210,    5.210}]}.
{[{{hackney_bstr,'-to_lower/1-lbc$^0/2-0-',2}, 170031,    0.000,  685.779},
  {{hackney_bstr,to_lower,1},                  14079, 1070.261,   62.526}],
 { {hackney_bstr,'-to_lower/1-lbc$^0/2-0-',2}, 184110, 1070.261,  748.305},     %  <----------
 [{{hackney_bstr,'-to_lower/1-lbc$^0/2-0-',2}, 170031,    0.000,  685.779},
  {{hackney_bstr,char_to_lower,1},             170031,  306.065,  305.583},
  {garbage_collect,                             970,   15.891,   15.891}]}.
```

The ACC column means accumulated time, this is for each function the total time spent in this function including subfunctions. The OWN column is the same, but without the subfunctions. Normally you want to sort by OWN to check which functions take up the most of the CPU.

Note the output is divided in blocks, and in the middle of each block there’s a line ending with a ‘%’ sign. That is the function each block is talking about, the other lines are the parents, and the childs of this function. From here you’re on your own.

In my case the fprof output showed that there were no more outliers with respect to performance, so this is where I stopped.